# Insert row into an empty table with INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM command in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I'm going to make a new table (PersonInformation) with columns of another one(Members) and some more columns like "Username", "Password" and "PersonId".

The command I used is:
'INSERT INTO myTable(Columns_in_PersonInformation...) SELECT (Columns_in_Members + new_columns) FROM Members, PersonInformation
WHERE Members.id = PersonInformation.PersonId'

I have two problems, **the first one** when the PersonInformation table is empty. The result is "0 rows affected" **the second one** when I add one row in the PersonInformation table, in each run, the code adds rows exponentially (2, 4, 8, 16, 32,...).

Here is my code:
'''

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PersonInformation (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, PersonId, Username, Password)
SELECT dbo.Members.FirstName,dbo.Members.LastName, dbo.Members.PhoneNumber, dbo.Members.EmailAddress ,@PersonId, @Username, @Pass
FROM dbo.Members , dbo.PersonInformation
WHERE dbo.Members.id = dbo.PersonInformation.PersonId
```

'''

Comment: can you make a fiddle to explain your issue in more detail http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First one when the PersonInformation table is empty*** - You can use left join in the query below. That will bring data from members even if personinformation is empty.

***The second one when I add one row in the PersonInformation table - data increases exponentially*** : Use the join syntax below with may be a distinct in query.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PersonInformation (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, PersonId, Username, Password)
SELECT members.FirstName,members.LastName, members.PhoneNumber, dbo.Members.EmailAddress ,@PersonId, @Username, @Pass
FROM dbo.Members members INNER JOIN dbo.PersonInformation pii
ON members.id = pii.PersonId
```

You can change it to RIGHT JOIN with DISTINCT or NULL check according to your condition

If you want only one record from the pii table, use a [SELECT TOP 1 CTE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7199f1e2-b14c-4f5f-b16e-4f05c9401b68/how-do-you-get-a-top-1-in-a-cte?forum=transactsql) or a [CROSS apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190849/7974050)

Comment: Thank you Amit,

Yes, you're right about the first question, but the problem is when I use LEFT JOIN the Member Table is completely copied into the PersonInformation table that I don't want that. 
I want only one row with this condition "Members.id = @PersonId" copied into the PersonInformation table and also add the "Username", "Password" and "PersonID" in from of the row.

Comment: Updated answer for inclusion of one record from pii table

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Amit,

**The second problem is solved** with the below changes:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PersonInformation (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, PersonId, Username, Password)
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Members.FirstName,dbo.Members.LastName, dbo.Members.PhoneNumber, dbo.Members.EmailAddress ,@PersonId, @Username, @Pass
FROM Members INNER JOIN dbo.PersonInformation
ON Members.id = @PersonId
```

The first problem still persists, but I added a dummy row to the table for now.